# Rpi Slave and Arduino Master

Tags: i2c, arduino

I am beginner of Raspberry Pi. Is it possible for me to use my Raspberry Pi as slave for Arduino Mega to be a master using I2C protocol?

I aim image processing by Raspberry Pi to send the steering angle, and the distance (self driving car) to the Arduino Mega board.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no workable way to make the Pi to work as an I2C slave.

The main Pi hardware/software driver is only a master.

There is an auxiliary hardware I2C driver which acts as a slave but there is no usable supporting software.

Comment: is it possible to use a voltage divider since i guess the problem is to go from 5V in arduino to 3.3 in rpi ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the voltage levels.  There is no software.  Several people have made attempts to write slave software for the Pi but no usable working software exists as far as I know.